# Make firefox ignore common file extensions as TLD's

Tags: firefox, tld

When I'm looking for information on a certain JS or CSS framework, I'm typing in (for example) `d3.js` or `skeleton.css` in Firefox. Firefox starts treating it like a domain name, and goes to www.d3.js.

How can I make Firefox ignore certain extensions as top-level domain names and instead, query my search engine?

Comment: Something I've gotten into the habit of doing is adding a space after the search term.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've found an answer to this by now but the technique I use is to create a shortcut to the search engine in the Preferences > Privacy & Security > One-Click Search Engines section, e.g.

[image]

Anything I know Firefox may use as a domain I simply prepend with `dd`, e.g. `dd d3.js`.